# Spatstat not available for R 3.2.3

Tags: r, installation, spatstat

I am trying to install the package Spatstat from a CRAN mirror in Germany (Münster) in R version 3.2.3, and it hasn't been possible because the package is not included into the packages list available to be installed.

There is a similar question about problems installing this package, but then the problem was an old version of R, which is not my case.

Does anybody know why is 'spatstats' not included in the list of packages of my CRAN mirror and how can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Go here: https://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/snapshot/2016-03-08/ This repostitory is frozen for version 3.2.3

Comment: Your problem _is_ an old version of R, where old means older than the current release (3.3.1) and older than required by the current latest version 1.46-1 of [spatstat](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=spatstat) (R >= 3.3.0).

Comment: The r-oldrel 1.45-2 version has the minimum R requirement 3.2.2. So, if you download the r-oldrel zip from Cran, you can install it directly from a zip file. Or go to the archive and download the tarball of the previous package version.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your answers. Yes, it was still old version problem. Have just updated it and it worked.